# how can we monitor Dell server RAID status under Centos

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge

Dell 1950 server running Dell PERC 6 RAID controller, how can we monitor the RAID status under Centos 7 without checking it in boot status? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How about PERC CLI? See here: http://www.dell.com/support/article/hu/hu/hubsdt1/sln283135/how-to-use-the-command-line-utility-on-your-dell-raid-controller-?lang=en

Comment: Thanks your reply, I am newbie, how can I check the current version number "x" for percli-x.xx-x.noarch.rpm so that I can type exact number to run rpm, thanks

Comment: You have to download that from Dell, I am not a Dell customer so I can't help with that one. Or maybe it's on the DVD came with the server.

Answer (score 1):

Stone's answer is correct, use the PERC CLI; his link gives good installation instructions, but currently doesn't lead to the RPM file.  See https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=52r3d for the latest version.

You can use "**yum localinstall**" instead of "**rpm -i**" on CentOS:

`yum -y localinstall perccli-007.0127.0000.0000-1.noarch.rpm`.

You have to run **perccli64** as root. Example usage:

`sudo /opt/MegaRAID/perccli/perccli64 -LDInfo -Lall -aALL`

Comment: I have another perccli, so to get all possible info (about controller #0):
`/opt/MegaRAID/perccli/perccli64 /c0/eall/sall show all`

Answer (score 0):

Tried perccli and megacli without success.

I managed to get status(health) of drives in a RAID environment using smartmontools.
What I didn't know was that they were hiding behind `/dev/sg#`

Example:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sg0 (1st physical disc)
smartctl -a /dev/sg1 (RAID1 virtual disc)
smartctl -a /dev/sg2 (2nd physical disc)
```

Not sure how to check RAID status, but helps a lot when checking for drive failure.